# Is there a correlation between the colonial power and the stability/success of the post colonial state?

Tags: british-empire, colonization, africa, french-empire

Looking at the history of Ghana relative to many post-colonial African states, it appears to be quite a successful and stable nation-state, both politically and economically, compared to many other post-colonial African nations. My hypothesis is that Ghana's success may to a large extent be the result of its being administered by the British during its colonial period, rather than the French, Belgians, or Portuguese, etc: Perhaps British colonies evolved into more stable, economically successful, independent states than their counterparts who are former French, Portuguese colonies, etc. A friend of mine from Ghana confirmed my hypothesis, but had no solid evidence to back it up.

A brief survey of some African countries seems to confirm my hypothesis: I compared the history of [Ghana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghana) (formerly Gold Coast under the British) with that of the [Democratic Republic of the Congo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo) (formerly "Belgian Congo"), [Republic of the Congo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_the_Congo) (formerly "French Congo"), and [Angola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angola) (formerly a Portuguese colony).  Compared to Ghana, the non-British colonies have been plagued with long and violent civil wars and political instability, which seriously impacted their economic growth and viability,

More research into the the success and stability of other former British colonies relative to their non-British counterparts also seems to back up such a theory: For example Jamaica, under the Brits from 1655 until 1958, and Trinidad/Tobago, administered by the Brits from 1889 until 1958 - in comparison to countries such as Cuba (Spain), Haiti (France), and the Dominican Republic(France/Spain/USA for a brief periods).

But my research here is admittedly quite superficial. Does historical analysis confirm or contradict my hypothesis that former British Colonies have been more successful as post-colonial states? More generally, can we find a pattern of success in the independent states that corresponds to their former colonial administrators (not necessarily the British)?

Although this question is admittedly complex, it can be answered with empirical analysis. A capable historian or economist should be able arrive at a clear conclusion, although not all will come to the same one, as is the case with any complex question. It requires extensive research to arrive at an accurate, well documented answer, but the answer itself can be quite concise and empirically based.

To side-step the issue of when to 'stop the clock' regarding measurement of success (today; five years ago; 10 years after independence....) the best answer might take into account the sum total of a former colony's history, such that a country like Angola, now quite successful, might not be considered successful relative to Ghana, considering the long and bloody civil wars that dominate much of Angola's history. But not being a historian or economist, I am not really the one to decide on the metrics: I turn to the Historians and experts among us for an appropriate way to quantify and answer this question.

Comment: The comments section is not for discussion. Please use The Time Machine for discussions: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine

Comment: I am accepting the answer of our friend Lennart, although he has admittedly only scratched the surface of this complex question, because he seems to be the only one with the knowledge and the moxie to even attempt to tackle it, and has done us all a service thereby. Still, I would welcome more in depth answers and perhaps an authoritative source that would help more definitively resolve this question.

Comment: Prof. Steven Fish at Berkeley once said in a lecture that he had crunched the empirical data and there was no evidence of any sort of relationship.  I have either a book of lecture notes with a cite somewhere, and will answer when I get a chance.

Comment: What about Sudan? Zimbabwe? Nigeria? Even Kenya? Also, Congo had its share of political instability but it's certainly no Angola or DR Congo and its HDI is above that of Ghana so it's not even clear there is a clear pattern to explain in the first place.

Comment: Noone knows how to control for all the other factors that aren't the identity of the colonizing power.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Although this question probably can't be resolved without years of comparative study, a quick indication of the answer can be done by looking at the current GDP of the countries as a reasonable measure of "stability and success". The cases are also very different between different continents and times, as colonization changed a lot during the period. Therefore I have looked at African colonization only, as this was done during a relatively consistent time, during the late 19th century, and ended at a relatively consistent time after WWII. It was also a similar type of colonization, with little settling from the colonial powers, with the exception of South Africa and Egypt which both had very different colonial histories (and therefore are excluded).

And the only conclusion that we possibly can draw from that is that Belgium was singularly bad, as all of the countries Belgium colonized has remained impoverished, although two of them were German colonies until 1918. Congo is still very poor, and this is perhaps not surprising, considering that Belgian colonization was extra-ordinarily brutal, but on the other hand, this is just a question of one (or possibly three) countries, so one should be wary of making any conclusions at all from that.

Italy, Spain and Portugal all have one rich colony, but Italy and Spain also have one poor and Portugal three poor, so no conclusion can be drawn there either.

Then remains British and French colonies, and there the numbers are quite similar. The average PPP GDP per capita in British former colonies is around $3.300, while in French former colonies $4.000. The richest former colonies have in both cases a GDP/capita of $17.000 and $16.500 respectively, and the poorest $400 and $580. That's not enough to claim any reasonable difference.

Hence, it is impossible from this to tell any reliable difference between different colonies, and it is certainly impossible to claim that Britain was a better colonial master than other countries, which the OP suspected.

Edit: Apparently I deleted the spreadsheet with my data, sorry about that, but the conclusion still stands: Post-colonial success/status/wealth is not connected to which empire was the colonizing force.

Comment: The comments section is not for discussion. Please use The Time Machine for discussions: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1560/the-time-machine

Comment: "Belgium was singularly bad, as all of the countries Belgium colonized has remained impoverished. This is perhaps not surprising, considering that Belgian colonization was extra-ordinarily brutal" Any ideas why Belgian colonialism was so specially bad?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: "Why" is always a difficult question.

Comment: I double-checked the German colonies and fixed some errors, which increased the difference between Britain and France, but I think the conclusion is still correct based on this data.

Comment: Wasn't the Congo a private possession of Leopold II as the "Congo Free State"? I didn't think it was formally part of Belgium until the early 1900s.

Comment: @Kobunite: Yes, but the border between the King and the State is always hard to define, so it's generally seen as a Belgian colony anyway.

Comment: It might be interesting to find out how much having a colonial company ruling over makes a difference in how developed the country comes out after independence. Mozambique comes to mind: for most of the colonial times it was ruled by colonial companies, that were mostly interested in profit (as opposed to development of infrastructure for the natives); the Belgian Congo is also an interesting example: it was not merely considered a private territory, it was used almost exclusively to make a profit, without any consideration for the natives living within.

Comment: This is becoming discussion again... Discussing what would be other questions seems a bit pointless.

Comment: You're right, let's keep on topic then.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - King Leopold, not the Belgian state used mercenaries rather than the Belgian military, and the goal was resource extraction, not political control. What political control there was in place was top-down ordered from Belgium, in contrast of the British and French policy of indirect rule, using the locals to administer to the indigenous population of the colonized territory.

Comment: Any chance you can add information about the outcome for Japanese colonies? I saw in a newspaper recently that Japanese nationalist contend that Taiwan, South Korea, and now China are well organized and somewhat rich due to Japanese control.

Comment: There's no significant Japanese control in any of those to my knowledge, and these territories gained freedom from Japan by war, so that seems highly unlikely. It's rather American influence in that case. And Japan's rule was short and not very colonial...

Comment: @LennartRegebro Perhaps [consider this information about Japanese colonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_colonial_empire). Seems like they controlled Taiwan and Korea for a length of time comparable to the scramble for Africa.

Comment: @axsvl77 Taiwan and South Korea has of course done extremely well, but yet again, I don't think that has anything to do with Japan, as they just like Belgium was extremely brutal in the occupation of most countries. I still suspect that the most important part is the manner of how they became independent, and where being liberated after WWII and being given freedom peacefully both presumably increases the chances of the post-liberation being peaceful.

Comment: @ Lennart Regebro Why are these places not worthy of comparison with the rest?

Comment: I just compared them, so I don't understand your question. Is anything unclear?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg The situation in the Belgium Congo became dire because King Leopold was allowed by his government to treat this African entity as his personal fiefdom. He ruled his African domain with the intention of exploiting its natural and human resources to fill his personal coffers and to basque in the reflected glory of developing, in his name, Belgium's infrastructure and public buildings. He committed appalling crimes against humanity including genocide.

Comment: That's obviously bask, not "basque" [sic]

Comment: The danger in this analysis is that causation might run in the other direction.  That is, the more powerful colonial power might choose to take the more populous and commercially successful areas.  For instance, Belgium and Germany were late to the table and might have been 'stuck' with more marginal areas.

Comment: Alas, the google doc spreadsheet linked to in this answer has since been deleted.

Comment: Ah well. But the data is outlined in the argument, so that should be good enough. The post colonial status of colonies isn't linked to which country they were colonized by.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are many factors that need to be considered. One that few may be aware of is that, as a result of WWII, once the British took control of Eritrea & Ethiopia, they systematically destroyed the modern infrastructure the Italians had built, on the racist grounds that the locals weren't smart enough/capable enough to use them. Haile Selassie had to block British engineers tasked with demolishing the electrical grid they had constructed in Addis Ababa -- one of the few installations not destroyed.

Answer (score 13):

There is in fact a small PDF available online which attempts to answer this question through  detailed study of a small area of the South Pacific. The islands of Vanuatu were administered jointly by the British and French.

The [author](http://www.be.wvu.edu/faculty_staff/dongwoo_yoo.htm) finds that "political indicators are in favor of British administration, but economic indicators are in favor of French administration".

His paper is called *Is British colonization better than that of the French?: A study of Vanuatu* and it's here:

http://eh.net/eha/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Yoo.pdf

Comment: Reminds me of a joke.  Canada had the chance to inherit American efficiency, French food and British Culture.  Instead they got American culture, French efficiency and British food.

Answer (score 8):

This poses an extraordinarily simplistic question. The histories of different 'colonies' are so utterly varied in their type and circumstances that it would be almost impossible to find useful examples for a contrasting case study. And what would be the point anyway?

'Colonies' which did particularly well, both before and after independence, are ones where there were large settler populations. For some reason 'settler communities' tend to make strong economic progress. The United States is such a 'settler community' almost entirely made up of migrants since the 18th century. Canada, Australia and New Zealand are 'settler countries'. But so is Singapore and a large portion of the population of such places as Malaysia, South Africa etc.

The settlers in Singapore and Malaysia were Chinese and Indians, who came to make their fortunes. Today they form the larger share of the bourgeoisie of those countries. The indigenous Malay population has been slower to urbanise and to industrialise.

What Britain and her liberal Empire mostly (with some obvious exceptions)  provided was a good system of law and commerce and a banking sector in which business could thrive, and in which people could retain the profits from their work and endeavour. They also provided a police service and mostly a peaceful state.

Problems that have arisen on decolonisation have mostly been in those large numbers of cases where there were divided communities. As the colonists left there was a often a struggle for control between different factions. Hence since 1945 British forces have had to stand between Malays and Chinese in Malaya, Greeks and Turks in Cyprus, Jews and Moslems in Palestine, Hindus and Moslems in India, Africans and Asians in East Africa, the Indigenous people of South Arabia (Aden) and the settlers of the port city of Aden. There are plenty of other examples.

I am vastly less well informed on French and Spanish colonisation/decolonisation.

This has not answered the question because I believe that there isn't one. But it may point to a few matters that need to be considered.

Answer (score 5):

I conducted a small survey of the (quite extensive) literature on this topic , and found that there are many different conclusions as to both whether and why the identity of a colonial power had an impact.   Quite frankly, the number of contradictory papers I found indicates that there is no scholarly consensus on this issue, and that it remains an ongoing debate (most of the papers I found were trying to rebut opposing claims, and found totally different things with the same data).  If you're curious, here is a small sample of some of the more interesting papers I found:

[Please note that I have academic access to scholarly databases; most of the links here are behind a paywall]

Blanton, Mason, and Athow (2001), in their paper [Colonial Style and Post-Colonial Ethnic Conflict in Africa](http://jpr.sagepub.com/content/38/4/473.full.pdf) compare British direct rule with French indirect rule and conclude:

> Results indicate that, after controlling for other salient factors, a British
>   colonial legacy is positively associated with ethnic conflict.

Bernhard, Reenock, and Nordstrom (2004) in [The Legacy of Western Overseas Colonialism on Democratic Survival](http://myweb.fsu.edu/creenock/Research/isq%202004.pdf) conclude that:

> We further find that the legacy of specific colonial powers has
>   an important effect on survival as well. Unlike previous studies, we find
>   that former Spanish colonies outperform British colonies when
>   colonialism is conceptualized holistically. However, when we break
>   colonial legacy into separate components (development, social fragmentation,
>   and the relationship between the state and civil society), we
>   find that the advantages former British colonies enjoy are attributable to
>   the legacy of the state/civil society relationship. Moreover, we show that
>   at least in the case of former British colonies, time spent under colonial
>   rule is positively associated with democratic survival.

Lange, Mahoney, and vom Hau (2006) in [Colonialism and Development: A Comparative Analysis of Spanish and British Colonies](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/499510):

> Our argument specifically shows that the historical processes through
>   which colonial institutions were installed and shaped subsequent development
>   differed dramatically for Spanish and British colonialism (see fig.
>   2). Spain colonized most heavily precolonial regions that were prosperous
>   because these areas offered the greatest potential for accumulation under
>   a mercantilist economic model. By contrast, Britain colonized most heavily
>   precolonial regions that were less complex because these areas offered
>   the greatest potential for capitalist accumulation. In turn, areas that were
>   heavily colonized by Spain saw the introduction of substantial mercantilist
>   institutions, and these institutions became important impediments to postcolonial
>   development. Areas that were heavily colonized by Britain saw
>   the introduction of substantial liberal institutions, and these institutions
>   were positively associated with development. Hence, both Spanish and
>   British colonialism reversed the fortunes of precolonial regions, but they
>   did so in very different ways.

In [Colonial Legacies and Economic Growth](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/30024490.pdf?acceptTC=true), Grier (1999) finds:

> I also find that the level of education at the time of independence can help to
>   explain much of the development gap between the former British and French
>   colonies in Africa. Even correcting for the length of colonization, which has
>   a positive influence on education levels and subsequent growth, I find support
>   for a separate British effect on education. That is, the data imply that the British
>   were more successful in educating their dependents than were the French.
>   The potential for expanding this work is enormous. Broadening the sample
>   to include the 63 countries from the original sample might help to explain
>   differences in Spanish and British post-colonial development. Looking further
>   at initial and current education rates could help illuminate the impact of
>   education and its persistence over time.

Answer (score 4):

Why ignore Australia, New Zealand & the United States - are they are not all former colonies of Great Britain?

The United States does particularly well, being the country with the highest GDP. They gained their independence in 1789, that is two centuries ago.

One may suppose, that most of the former colonial nations that aren't doing so well are still building their political institutions. This is the work of several generations. After large-scale economics requires strong political institutions.

One could also perhaps point out that these countries could industrialise relatively rapidly as this is the social environment that colonists came from, and who form the dominant & majority population. Whereas places like Africa or India this 'lesson' in modernity would have had to be absorbed by the indigenous population.

Comment: Marx on Western Australia ( http://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1867-c1/ch33.htm ) and the relatively common place findings about finance capital preceeding federation (Noel Butlin) seem to falsify your argument in the Australian case.  Capital preceded political institutions.

Comment: @russell: If it invalidates it in the Australian case, then it should invalidates in the others too. Are you talking about London finance capital funding these colonial expeditions? According to [Butlins obituary](http://oa.anu.edu.au/obituary/butlin-noel-george-184) 'before the publication of his major book Investment in Australian Economic Development (1964), historians saw Australia's past almost solely in terms of rural development. Noel, however, was able to show that, as early as the second half of the nineteenth century, more investment was being undertaken in urban than in rural areas,

Comment: ...and that the public sector was a major player in this process'. The public sector surely requires a political formation?

Comment: Connell & Irving's Class Structure in Australian History ought to explain.  The "political formation" was substantially off-shore and administered as an external colonial administration.  Local administration and state industry lagged behind the development in the world-system's centre until after capital formation.  Representation came after capitalisation (and never mirrored the basis of capitalisation, being restricted to state or dominion governance).  Also, a cursory look at UK corporations law in the 19th century shows the state lagged behind capital in the *core*.

Comment: @Russell: I understand what you say up to 'Representation came after capitalisation'. But what does the following sentence mean 'and never mirrored the basis of capitalisation, being restricted to state or dominion governance'?

Comment: Australian capital's profits flow off shore (ie: UK or US); outside of the reach of the State claiming sovereignty.  The colonies, and later federal States of the Dominion of Australia never had a democracy that had a reach to control the economy (ie: reps in UK parliament).  Attempts to alter this by altering the structure of national debt resulted in external sovereignty being applied to Australia in the NSW case of Lang.  ie: That even in "Settler society" colonies, the economy was still colonial and the "democratic" state never controlled the real economy of the state.

Comment: The nations mentioned had the original peoples and cultures all but wiped out by disease and genocide during the heyday of colonization. The original question, whether explicit in this or not, was asking which European Colonial power's flavor of White Supremacist rule was better than the others. There is a good question in here, tho, as to the differences between true colonization - as in the US and ANZAC - and Empire - as in India, Asia and Africa.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - you are raising some interesting points but I don't see an answer. As I mentioned in the question, the issue of when to 'stop the clock' is indeed problematic.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who studied in Indonesia (former colony of Dutch) and Singapore (former colony of British), I can say very well the difference lies in the education investment made by the British.

This simple [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/daryl_tanyl/chapter-4-how-did-the-british-rule-singapore) (slide 21) shows very clearly the investment made by the British in their crown colony:

[image]

The Dutch, however, did not do the same for its colonies (i.e. Indonesia), since the main target was to utilize the colony to increase revenue of the VOC. There are numerous article on this issue if you can read the local language. Technically, even the textbook recorded the absence of education service for the native, unless they were willing to 'cooperate' with the Dutch.

Post-colonization-wise, it depends on the nation itself, whether they are able to utilize the 'advantage' of their education. There are cases where the educated generation is rendered meaningless due to (civil) war, too.

Answer (score 1):

The Portuguese colonies were amongst the most developed. It was the scramble for their mineral resources, namely Angola's oil, which led the superpowers of the time to destabilize them, leading to civil wars and economic decline.